# Mongoose populate with extra fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Match and User schemas like these

```
var MatchSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    players: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    active: Boolean,
    createdAt: Date
});  
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true }
});
```

Here I populate the player object with users, but what I'd like to do is populate the object and add an additional field to every user in match schema only so they would look like this

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    status: String
});
```

Is it possible? If no how should I approach this then?

Comment: Is your match and user schema declared in the same file or different files?